# index error in python (work with excel program)

Tags: python, excel

```
plans_dtype = ["str", "str", "int", "int", "int", "int","int", "int","int", "int", "int", "int","int", "int"]
/ other code/

plans_dtype_dict = {plans_cols[i]:plans_dtype[i] for i in range(0,len(plans_cols))}
plans_dtype_dict
```

i want to create a dictionary where i want to take plans_cols as a key and plans_dtype as its value. However, it gives

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 plans_dtype_dict = {plans_cols[i]:plans_dtype[i] for i in range(0,len(plans_cols))}
      2 plans_dtype_dict

Input In [24], in <dictcomp>(.0)
----> 1 plans_dtype_dict = {plans_cols[i]:plans_dtype[i] for i in range(0,len(plans_cols))}
      2 plans_dtype_dict

IndexError: list index out of range
```

i tried to check my code and its list however, i dont understand why it gives an index error

Comment: Use `len(plans_cols) - 1`  as the upper bound in the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

```
plans_dtype = ["str", "str", "int", "int", "int", "int", "int", "int", "int", "int", "int", "int", "int", "int"]
```

**Method 1**

```
dic = {k : plans_dtype[i] for i, k in enumerate(plans_cols)}
```

**Method 2**

```
dic = {plans_cols[i] : plans_dtype[i] for i in range(len(plans_col))}
```